# Validating Subversion Android Studio Project Build: New Project from SVN

Tags: android-studio, svn, build

Given an existing Android Studio (4.0.1) project that builds and deploys properly and that has an associated SVN repository, I would like to create a separate Android Studio project and get that to also build properly.  The purpose is to 1) Prove that the SVN repository is complete (has everything needed to get a build working), 2) Document the steps required to get this Android Studio project out of SVN and building.

Selecting `Get from Version Control` from Android Studio's welcome screen, I can specify the SVN repository and checkout:

[image: SVN Checkout Options Screen]

Take the default/latest format for SVN:

[image: SVN format 1.8]

And indicate I'd like to make a project out of the contents of the SVN repository:

[image: Android Studio asking if I want to make a project]

Then I'm presented with an option that I'm unsure how to answer:

[image: Android Studio Import options screen]

I have tried them all, none successfully.  Rather than go into the details of each here, I would like to learn about which option makes sense in which situation.

The original project was created 5 or more years ago with Android Studio's 'start a new project' wizard. I've use Android Studio's default build stuff all along, and upgraded Android Studio and the various plug-ins when nagged sufficiently.  I'm not sure what the important build artifacts are (or artifacts critical to a clean import are), and if those  artifacts are indeed in the SVN repository and up to date.  I can copy the project in the file system and rename things to get it to build, but creating another instance is not the question; the source must be exclusively the SVN repository.

I'm eager to make this question complete, so please do me the favor of specific criticism in the comments so I may improve the question or remove it, as needed.

The optimal person to answer this question would know much more about how Android Studio builds work than I do. I have strictly "cookbook" level knowledge. So without significant study, I am unable to validate intricacies of the process without more knowledgeable people to help.

Answer (score 1):

The last `Import Project` dialog from this SO question only appears if the contents pulled from SVN are not a complete project.

In other words, if what gets pulled is a complete project, the project just opens, without having to go through any other questions and/or selections. Otherwise, other logic takes over and Android Studio tries to create a legit project for you from the bits it finds.

[image: Android Studio Import Project Dialogs if Incomplete Project Found during import]

The solution is to make sure that the check-in from the original working project is complete, including gradle files.  If Android Studio is set to view the "Android" artifact view, then everything in the list should display in the VCS "included in source control" and "checked-in" font color.